# Export BoxGeometry as Json from Worker

Tags: three.js

I try to export a Boxgeometry that has been crated in a Js Worker. I performed some vertices displacement within the worker.

Back to the main thread, I get this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'index')

Code in Worker:

```
self.postMessage(result.toJSON());
```

Back in main:

```
myWorker.addEventListener("message", function handleMessageFromWorker(msg) {
  const loader = new THREE.BufferGeometryLoader();
  var texturedGeometry = loader.parse(msg.data);
});
```

[image]

Any idea what's going wrong ?